# On Postback, how to get the Column that I am sorting by in my GridView?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

On Postback, how to get the Column that I am sorting by (by clicking on the column) in my `GridView`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you need to grab the [`SortExpression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sortexpression.aspx) from the `GridView` object when handling the [`Sorted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sorted.aspx) event.